# How to loop this properly

Tags: c#

I have tried looping this it didnt work for me please help me im trying to learn c# and it would help alot if you would help me

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
{
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to check, if its a number or not: ");
    int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    bool isLessThan10000000000 = myInt < 10000000000;

    Console.WriteLine("Is it a Number? {0}", isLessThan10000000000);

    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue (Y/N)? ");


    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'Y')
    {
          

    }
    else
    {


    }

}
```

Comment: you don't have any loop in your code.  have you tried learning about a `while` loop or a `do while` loop?

Comment: i did try it didnt work

Comment: @BetaSapphire A pointer with regards to converting the user input to an INT. You really want to check if the input can be converted to INT, and if not then give user some feedback to correct their input. To check the conversion is possible use this:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`do while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement) loop

it's about the same as a `while` loop expect it evaluates the condition after the loop instead of before

```
do
{
    //Your code
}
while(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'Y');
```

Comment: Or `while(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);` which can be more readable